# Scala how to check Unit for equality?

Tags: java, scala

My code is as follows:

```
myBuffer = myInput.read()
 if (!myBuffer.!=(-1)) {
    return -1
 }
```

`myBuffer` is declared as a var int at the top of the class and I am trying to check when it equals -1 so that I can return -1. When I tried doing it the Java way, like so:

```
if ( (myBuffer = myInput.read()) == -1) {
     return -1;
}
```

I got an warning saying that a test for equality with Unit will always give false, which was verified when I ran it and it never exited the loop that this code was a part of. This feels like it should be trivial but I haven't been able to find a solution to this. Any ideas?

Comment: The assignment `myBuffer = myInput.read()` returns  a `Unit`, and not the value of `myInput.read()`. What are you trying to accomplish overall?

Comment: I'm trying to read from a file (myInput is an InputStream) and stop reading at the end of file (indicated by the -1). I wrote this code in Java and am trying to port it to Scala

Answer (score 0):

using `var` is not recommended in Scala as you may know.

try `scala.io.StdIn.readLine()`